# Active directory, limit permission on ldap, allow only to read self profile

Tags: active-directory, permissions, ldap

Is possible to limit the visibility of a standard LDAP user?

I'd like standard users are allowed to read only their personal information, and deny them to read someone else profile.

I tried to apply a deny permission on the OU(organizational unit) but there are some default grant permission on the user object and since they are in a closer level, they can override the deny setting.

by default "authenticated users" can read on an user object:

general,public,personal,web informations

I could:

- remove user by user these "authenticated users" permissions,
- add user by user "self" read permissions
- deny users read on the OU's sub-objects

but is quite painful and I'm not sure if it can cause malfunctions.

someone have some advise? Is there an easier approach?

thanks.